# How to send cmd.exe arguments to a Python script?

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, cmd

I need to launch the following command in cmd.exe:

```
%comspec% /c "cd /d d:\Python27\Scripts\ && python test.py "nombreaaààççtestyï_XJ00080183.avi""
```

...and use the argument in my Python script:

```
nameficheroData= sys.argv[1]
print type(nameficheroData)
fichero = open(nameficheroData, 'w' ) 
fichero.write('nameficheroData.\n') 
fichero.close()
```

And write the text: `nombreaa+á+á+º+ºtesty+»_XJ00080183.avi` to the file.

In the command prompt:

```
chcp
Active: 850
```

In my Python 2.7 system:

```
>>> import sys
>>> print(sys.getdefaultencoding())
ascii
```

What is the proper way to do this?

```
nombreaaààççtestyï_XJ00080183.avi
nombreaa+á+á+º+ºtesty+»_XJ00080183.avi
```

It's not respecting the same name.

Comment: What does the code you have do—what's the problem?

Comment: nombreaaààççtestyï_XJ00080183.avi it's not equal: nombreaa + A + A + º + + ºtesty» _ XJ00080183.avi

Comment: Look into `sys.argv`. For more complicated code, try the `argparse` module

Comment: You are passing an argument from cmd.exe, to Python, to the filesystem. Can you see if the value is changing along the way?

Comment: My active code page is the same as yours, `850`. However when I run your code on my Windows 7 system from the command line the way shown in your question, it **does** produce a file named `nombreaaààççtestyï_XJ00080183.avi` with the right contents—so I can't reproduce the problem. What operating system and version of Python are you using?

Comment: @martineau, cmd.exe processes its command line as Unicode text (UTF-16LE) and reads Unicode from the console, but apparently the OP is using a crusty old batch file, which gets decoded using the current console codepage, which defaults to OEM (e.g. 850). This ends up with mojibake because Python 2.7 uses the legacy ANSI encoding (e.g. 1252). What to do: save the file as ANSI text, and on the first line of the batch file, change the console to use the system ANSI codepage, e.g. `chcp 1252`. Then cmd will properly decode this to Unicode and Python 2.7 will encode it back as ANSI.

Comment: @eryksun: The OP isn't using a batch file (and neither was I). He's running the shell and typing the command shown at the top of the question at the prompt.

Comment: @martineau, this won't happen if the command is entered at the command prompt. cmd.exe reads Unicode from the console via `ReadConsoleW`, and it calls the wide-character function `CreateProcessW` -- so the command line is Unicode all the way until Python 2.7, which, via the CRT, gets an ANSI encoded copy via `GetCommandLineA`.

Comment: @martineau, but my first comment does get the source of the mojibake wrong. It's probably the case that the batch file is encoded as ANSI, and cmd.exe is decoding it improperly as OEM. The solution I proposed would still work, but another option is to ensure that the batch file is saved as OEM text.

Comment: @eryksun: There's no batch file involved.

Comment: @eryksun: Because the OP wrote "I need to launch in MS-DOS the command:". Why don't you just sit back and relax for a while and see what, if anything, else the OP has to say? Or, better yet, post your solution and see if they accept it.

Comment: thanks,I was solved send string with chcp 65001 thanks!!!!                                 %comspec% /c "cd /d d:\Python27\Scripts\ && chcp 65001 && python test.py "€%$ěščřžýáíéi""

Comment: Then you probably have a batch file saved as UTF-8 without a BOM, which matches the example mojibake in your question. A more common solution would be to save the batch file as the OEM encoding, which is codepage 850 in your case. You'll find that unmodified Python 2 doesn't work right with codepage 65001, e.g. `python -c "print u'spam'"` fails. In that case I suggest that you install and enable the `win_unicode_console` module, which makes `sys.std*` use the console's wide-character API instead of legacy codepages.